# FluentValidation rule on 2 fields at least one filled

Tags: validation, blazor, fluentvalidation, blazor-validation

I have a class Address with properties Phone and Mobile. I want to check that at least one of these properties is filled.
I put comments on each rule to say what's going wrong

```
public class AddressValidator : BaseValidator<Address>
{
    public AddressValidator()
        : base()
    {

        //NOT WORKING
        RuleFor(x => x)
           .Must(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Phone) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Mobile))
           .WithMessage("Phone or mobile mandatory");

        //WORKS ONLY ON MOBILE FIELD CHANGED
        RuleFor(m => m.Mobile).Must((a, Mobile) =>
                    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Phone) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mobile)))
                    .WithMessage("Phone or mobile mandatory");

         //WORKS ONLY ON MOBILE FIELD CHANGED
        RuleFor(m => m.Phone).Must((a, Phone) =>
                    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Mobile) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone)))
                    .WithMessage("Phone or mobile mandatory");
    }
   
}
```

this is my form in blazor

```
<EditForm Context="billing" Model=@Address>
 <FluentValidationValidator DisableAssemblyScanning="@true" @ref="validatorAddress"></FluentValidationValidator>                   
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <TextBox TValue="string"
                         @bind-Value=@Address.Phone />
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Address.Phone )" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <TextBox TValue="string"
                         @bind-Value=@Address.Mobile/>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Address.Mobile)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
   </Editform>
```

How can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try to split the validation like this

```
RuleFor(m => m.Mobile).NotEmpty().When(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Phone)).WithMessage("Phone or mobile mandatory");
RuleFor(m => m.Phone).NotEmpty().When(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Mobile)).WithMessage("Phone or mobile mandatory");
```

Comment: tthe problem is that if I initially have error message under the 2 textboxes and I change for example Mobile value, the error clears only under Mobile textbox and under Phone textbox the error remains when It has to be canceled because at least one field between Phone and Mobile is not Empty